# use Subprocess module to run phpunit test suites

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

I am trying to use python subprocess and mulitprocessing module to run the php unit test cases for coverage. Running the PHP coverage standalone for the whole codebase takes a lot of time, so I am trying to parallelize it by running the coverage for different test suites and then combining the result. For this I am using Python Subprocess and Multiprocessing module, the issue I am facing is some of the test suites are running correctly but some are erring out.

I am getting following error PHP Startup : apc_mmap failed, with error code -9, -11 for some of the processes. Also for some of the test suites that have a lot of test cases like around 15K, the entire output of the phpunit run is not coming in.

I am running 6 subprocesses at a time, as thats the cpu_core available in my VM.

1. I am initializing the subprocesses using the following command

   ```
   Popen(cmd, shell=True, close_fds=True, stdout=file1, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   ```
2. And I am using `pr.poll()` to check if the process is complete.

I tried changing the bufsize to 1 while initializing the Popen object but still not getting the entire output of Popen class.

Can somebody please suggest any pointers on what I might be doing wrong ?

Here's the sample code -

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import subprocess
def createProcesses(testSuites):
    procs = []
    maxProcs = mp.cpu_count()
    logfile = open("./testFile.txt", "w+")
    for suites in testSuites:
        while len(procs) != maxProcs:
            manageProcs(procs)
        procs.append(createWorkerTestProcesses)
    while len(procs):
        manageProcs(procs, logfile)
    logfile.close()

def createWorkerTestProcesses(suite):
    f= open(suite+"txt", "w+")
    cmd = "php -d auto_prepend_file=/usr/local/www/data/tests/app_includes/auto_prepend_for_tests.php /usr/local/www/data/tests/sdk/bin/phpunit.phar --configuration phpunit.xml --testsuites " + suite
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, close_fds=True, stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    return p, f, suite

def manageProcs(proclist, logfile):
    for p, f, suite in proclist:
        if p.poll is not None:
            f.seek(0)
            logfile.write(f.read())
            f.close()
            proclist.remove((p,f,suite))
    sleep(0.5)

def main():

    createProcesses(testSuites)

main()
```

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer unless you can give something we can reproduce at least one of the errors you're hitting with. I suspect you have proprietary code here, so maybe you can create .a small but toy example that has the same behavior?

Comment: I have attached the sample code

Comment: Is this the code? It looks like you aren't calling this function by its exact name: `createWorkerTestProcesses`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, i was able to find the error by tailing the linux logs. It appears the process is causing segfault but I am not sure how to resolve it

Comment: Darn. I'm sorry for your troubles. It seems like you need a different question then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this so future readers aren't tempted to solve the problem you've already gotten past (which is not really reproducible here.) If you can narrow down the other problem you're currently facing, please open another question targeting the segfaults.